# Source for downloading the FERET database

Tags: database, opencv, image-processing, dataset, computer-vision

Am working on the gender estimation, i need FERET database for training purpose. I searched in many websites but am unable to download, so please anyone kindly say the source for downloading this FERET database.
Thanks.

Comment: http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/colorferet.cfm

Comment: alternatively: http://www.openu.ac.il/home/hassner/Adience/data.html

Comment: thanks, i got it from sending a mail to corresponding person

Comment: @berak please send me FERET Database